# Showing that $A^*$ is and ideal and that "$*$" is multiplicative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $E/F$ be an extension of algebraic number fields and $\mathcal{O}_E$ and $\mathcal{O}_F$ be the ring of integers. Define $$A^*=\mathcal{O}_EA,$$ where A is an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_F$.

Prove that $A^*$ is and ideal of of $\mathcal{O}_E$ and $(AB)^*=A^*B^*$.

I tried to show the following:

1. $A^*$ is non-empty
2. $A^*$ is closed under addition
3. $A^*$ "absorbs" the multiplication with the elements from the ring $\mathcal{O}_E$

Sure  $A^*$ is non-empty because $A$ and $\mathcal{O}_E$ are. And the third property is trivial. But I'm struggling to show that it's closed under addition. I took two elements $x,y \in  A^*$ which are of the form $e_ia_i$ $(i=1,2 )$ where $e_i \in \mathcal{O}_E$ and $a_i \in A$. Now $x+y=e_1a_1+e_2a_2$. How to show this belongs to  $A^*$?

To show that $(AB)^*=A^*B^*$ I simply use the fact that the ideals of ring of integers are finitely generated and then just multiply. Let $A=[a_1,\, \dots ,\,a_n]$ and $B=[b_1,\, \dots ,\, b_k]$. Then 
$$
A^*B^*=
(\mathcal{O}_EA)(\mathcal{O}_EB)=
\mathcal{O}_E[a_1,\, \dots ,\,a_n]\mathcal{O}_E[b_1,\, \dots ,\, b_k]=
\mathcal{O}_E(\mathcal{O}_F a_1 + \dots + \mathcal{O}a_n)\mathcal{O}_E(\mathcal{O}_F b_1 + \dots + \mathcal{O}_Fb_k) \quad = 
(\mathcal{O}_E a_1 + \dots + \mathcal{O}_Ea_n)(\mathcal{O}_E b_1 + \dots + \mathcal{O}_Eb_k) \quad = 
\mathcal{O}_E[a_1b_1  ,\, a_1b_2,\, \dots,\, a_1b_k,\, a_2b_1,\, \dots,\, a_nb_k]=
(AB)^*.$$

Is the work I've managed to do correct and how to complete the first proof? I also wonder if there is name for this operation "$*$".

Comment: It's a special case of [ideal extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_and_contraction_of_ideals#Extension_of_an_ideal) coming from the obvious inclusion $\mathcal{O}_F \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_E$.

Comment: @BrandonCarter But can you tell me if my work is okay?

Comment: @BrandonCarter And also in the wikipedia link there is no proof that it is a ideal.

Comment: @Kplusn: The construction of the extension of an ideal takes the ideal generated by several elements (in this case the elements of A). It is, by definition, an ideal.

Comment: @BrandonCarter Then I think I don't understand the construction properly. Because I can't see right away that it fulfils the definition of an ideal.